# Get website header with IP

Tags: php

I want to get the header from a website with the IP address.

I used `get_header()` but this only works with URL! Are there other ways to do this?
Without using `gethostbyaddre`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have an IP address, e.g.: `127.0.0.1`
- You want to use `get_headers()` (with trailing **s**)
- ...but `get_headers()` [expects a URL](http://php.net/get_headers):

  ```
  array get_headers ( string $url [, int $format = 0 ] )
  ```
- You add `http://` and you get a URL: `http://127.0.0.1`—voilá!

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use an IP. Since there's no code, I can't tell where you're going wrong. But I can tell how it should be done:

```
$url = 'http://173.194.65.101/';
$headers = get_headers($url);
print_r($headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

use  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cUrl call than analyse and extract the headers from the server's reponse.